# Hot to show user's youtube videos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube, youtube-api, google-api

I have a project (Rails based), where users log in using Google Oauth 2. Are there any way to get that user's videos from Youtube?

After logging in through Oauth2 I recieve `access_token` and `refresh_token`. [There is a gem](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it) for using youtube API, so I tried this approach:

```
#credentials contain my youtube answer
client = YouTubeIt::OAuth2Client.new(
  client_access_token: credentials[:token],
  client_refresh_token: credentials[:refresh_token],
  client_id: "my_application_client_id",
  client_secret: "my_application_client_secret",
  dev_key: "my_application_dev_key",
  expires_at: credentials[:expires_at]
)
```

But when I try to fetch user videos:

```
client.my_videos
```

I recieve the `Token invalid` error in API answer.

Some ideas about how to show user his videos?

Answer (score 0):

You need to head over to [https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/wiki/How-To:-Use-OAuth-2](https://github.com/kylejginavan/youtube_it/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-OAuth-2) and read up on how to get a `dev_key` and a `client_id` and a `client_secret`. Because you not only need the authorization of the user to query his videos, but you also need to authorize your application with the youtube API